# value withSQL not found

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

still new in the scalikeJDBC usage,
im having this error when compiling my code which was generated from the "reverse engineering" of mysql Db with scalikejdbc 1.7.7
"not found: value withSQL"

any idea?

```
def find(id: String)(implicit session: DBSession = autoSession): Option[EmployeeBasicDetail] = {
withSQL { 
  select.from(EmployeeBasicDetail as ebd).where.eq(ebd.id, id)
}.map(EmployeeBasicDetail(ebd.resultName)).single.apply()
```

}

from the method above the compiler points to function "withSQL"   not found: value withSQL

thanks

Comment: Please provide some source code to help debugging...

Comment: I have edited the question with some code

Comment: Sorry if these sound as silly questions but have you imported the library both in project and in source file?

Comment: I see that its a Human error, I generated two different models with both the 2.0  and 1.7 version.and i see that in the 2.0 version SQLInterpolation is not imported. Thanks